# Can't find MergeModules after install

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, redistributable

I just installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package ATL Security Update from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14431#filelist (x86), and expected to find the merge modules to use on my machine. Unfortunately, I cannot find them at \Program Files\Common Files\Merge Modules\ folder. Any idea where I can find them please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was able to extract the mergemodules from the downloaded .exe file using 7-zip software. After a unzipping and unpacking all the contents of the executable file, I found the merge modules, even verified the version was correct one I needed, and was able to successfully build my setup project, and install my app correctly on client machine.